# Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ a subset of $X$. Is $ Fr (Int A ) = Fr(A)$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ a subset of $X$. 
Is $ Fr (Int A ) = Fr(A)$?

I can't find a counterexample or prove that it's true.

Comment: What is "Fr"???

Comment: @amsmath  $ Fr A =Cl (A) \cap Cl(X\A) $

Comment: @amsmath It's the boundary.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you.

Comment: @user15269 I don't know where "Fr" comes from, but the common notation of the boundary of a set $A$ is $\partial A$.

Comment: @amsmath in spanish Fr is common as well, probably in french too.

Comment: @Javi But this is an English site, right?

Comment: @amsmath yes, but the OP might not be aware of the usual notation in english or  (s)he might simply think that Fr is used too. I just wanted to explain where Fr comes from.

Comment: @Javi Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual topology, $Fr(\Bbb{Q})=\Bbb{R}$, but $Int\Bbb{Q}=\emptyset$, so $Fr(Int\Bbb{Q})=\emptyset$.